# Trigger when page loads

Tags: firefox, onload

I am developing Firefox extension and I am trying trigger my function each time page is loaded.

I tried with Event Listener and it works fine when you type url in urlbar.
But when you click link on page it doesn't seem to trigger.

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", MyFunc, false);
```

Could someone point me in right direction?

Cheers